# How do I create a TypeScript interface for accepting a list of JSX.Elements with a key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to be able to pass in an array of JSX elements into a component, but I want to make sure that they all must have at least a `key` property.

Is this possible?

E.g.

```
  <MyComponent
    list={[
      <div key="test1" />,
      <div key="test2" />,
      <div /> <-- this would fail as doesn't have a key
    ]}
  >
  ...
  </MyComponent>
```

Comment: No, it is not possible. As far as TS is concerned, the type of *any JSX expression* is `JSX.Element` or one of the types in `ReactNode` (when using React). There's no type information conveyed.

Comment: I have figured out a way to do this, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this

```
type ElementWithKey = React.ReactElement<{key: string}>;
```

This then gives the correct errors in TypeScript when the key is missing.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me: https://tsplay.dev/wXOXQW; care to show how it's done?

Comment: @pink that is interesting, i'm not sure why it's not working on your link, see screenshot added to my answer showing it working using your exact code in my project.